# Efficient way to backup original laptop for warranty purposes?

Tags: boot, partitioning, backup

I purchased a new HP laptop.  I will wipe out Windows completely and install Ubuntu (not dual boot).

However, I want to be able to restore the disk to its original condition (boot + partitions + original OS + original software + etc) if I ever need to send the laptop back for warranty purposes.

What is the best way to save the original 1TB disk to a network location, so I don't need a > 1TB backup drive?  Also, what would the appropriate recovery steps be for the solution?

(Note: I will simply boot into an Ubuntu Live USB on first boot).

Comment: To make a backup of the whole HDD you need some tool as [Clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/) and large enough external hard drive or USB memory sticks (keep in mind they are slow). @ZeissIkon is right the backup of a fresh installation shouldn't so big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Backup

1. **Boot Using Live USB**

   On the computer that is being backed up, boot an Ubuntu Live USB, and open a terminal window.
2. **List Partition Information**

   The disk that I want to backup is `/dev/nvme0n1`. Replace `nvme0n1` with your disk. You can use the Disks application in Ubuntu to see a list of disks and their device names.

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
   ```

   This is how my disk was partitioned from the manufacturer.

   ```
   Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   Disklabel type: gpt
   Disk identifier: 1C949023-866B-4764-B397-252D5125277C

   Device              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
   /dev/nvme0n1p1       2048     534527     532480   260M EFI System
   /dev/nvme0n1p2     534528     567295      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
   /dev/nvme0n1p3     567296 1972772863 1972205568 940.4G Microsoft basic data
   /dev/nvme0n1p4 1972772864 1974779903    2007040   980M Windows recovery environment
   /dev/nvme0n1p5 1974779904 2000396287   25616384  12.2G Microsoft basic data
   ```
3. **Backup Partition Table**

   Run the following from computer that is being backed up to create a backup of your partition table.

   ```
   cd ~/
   sudo sgdisk --backup=nvme0n1.gpt /dev/nvme0n1
   ```

   Copy the backup to the `/mnt/data/Backup/` directory on the remote computer.
   Replace `/mnt/data/Backup/` with the existing backup location on your remote computer. Replace `remote_user` and `REMOTE_COMPUTER` accordingly.

   ```
   rcp ~/nvme0n1.gpt remote_user@REMOTE_COMPUTER:/mnt/data/Backup/
   ```

   After verifying the file was copied safely, delete the local copy.

   ```
   rm ~/nvme0n1.gpt
   ```
4. **Tips**

   - You can actually backup each partition in parallel, using different terminal windows in step 5, below. Just be sure to execute `sudo -i` in each new terminal window.
   - To monitor your connectivity during the backup process do the following.

     On the computer being backed up, open a terminal and type:

     ```
     ping REMOTE_COMPUTER.local
     ```

     On the remote computer, open a terminal and type:

     ```
     ping <IP ADDRESS OF COMPUTER BEING BACKED UP>
     ```

     (I think simply `ping ubuntu.local` may also work since you are running from a Live USB).

     In my opinion, the constant pinging keeps the connection between computers alive. I noticed that once in a while, one of the computers would become unreachable; I resisted the temptation to kill the `dd` process, and the other computer would begin responding to the ping requests in a few minutes.
   - If you want to see progress and estimated time (ETA) of the backup process, you can incorporate the `pv` command into in step 5 below.  I did not do this during backup, but you can see steps 6 and 7 in the **Restore** section on how to use `pv`.
5. **Backup Each Partition to Remote Computer**

   Run the following from the computer that is being backed up to create a backup of each partition.

   The backup files are placed in the `/mnt/data/Backup/` directory on the remote computer.

   Replace `/mnt/data/Backup/` with the existing backup location on your remote computer. Replace `remote_user` and `REMOTE_COMPUTER` accordingly.

   Execute the `dd` command for each partition listed in step 2 above. For example, for each of my five partitions, I executed the following:

   ```
   sudo -i

   # (1) 260.0 MiB
   dd if=/dev/nvme0n1p1 | ssh remote_user@REMOTE_COMPUTER dd of=/mnt/data/Backup/nvme0n1p1.img

   # (2) 16.0 MiB
   dd if=/dev/nvme0n1p2 | ssh remote_user@REMOTE_COMPUTER dd of=/mnt/data/Backup/nvme0n1p2.img

   # (3) 940.4 GiB
   date; dd if=/dev/nvme0n1p3 | gzip -1 - | ssh remote_user@REMOTE_COMPUTER dd of/mnt/data/Backup/=nvme0n1p3.img.gz; date

   # (4) 980.0 MiB
   dd if=/dev/nvme0n1p4 | ssh remote_user@REMOTE_COMPUTER dd of=/mnt/data/Backup/nvme0n1p4.img

   # (5) 12.2 GiB
   dd if=/dev/nvme0n1p5 | ssh remote_user@REMOTE_COMPUTER dd of=/mnt/data/Backup/nvme0n1p5.img
   ```

   Notice that for partition number 3, I chose to `gzip` the partition due to its large size. Since this was the main Windows partition, and it had never been used, I was confident that most of the bits on the disk would be zeros, allowing for significant compression. If the disk is used, or you do not use compression, the backup file may be too large; also copying the data to the remote computer may take much longer. Partition numbers 1, 2, 4, and 5 were not that large, and I had storage space to back them up, so I didn't bother compressing them, but you could also use `gzip` for all partitions if you want to.

   Here is an example output for the third partition.

   ```
   root@ubuntu:~ # date; dd if=/dev/nvme0n1p3 | gzip -1 - | ssh remote_user@REMOTE_COMPUTER dd of=/mnt/data/Backup/nvme0n1p3.img.gz; date

   Fri Nov  3 03:23:06 EDT 2017
   remote_user@REMOTE_COMPUTER's password: 
   1972205568+0 records in
   1972205568+0 records out
   1009769250816 bytes (1.0 TB, 940 GiB) copied, 4422.5 s, 228 MB/s
   45542474+1 records in
   45542474+1 records out
   23317746863 bytes (23 GB, 22 GiB) copied, 4417.97 s, 5.3 MB/s
   Fri Nov  3 04:36:49 EDT 2017
   ```

   Here are the list of files that were backed up.

   ```
   remote_user@REMOTE_COMPUTER:/mnt/data/Backup $ ls -g -o -h
   total 36G
   -r--r--r-- 1  18K Nov  3 01:14 nvme0n1.gpt
   -r--r--r-- 1 260M Nov  3 00:55 nvme0n1p1.img
   -r--r--r-- 1  16M Nov  3 00:55 nvme0n1p2.img
   -r--r--r-- 1  22G Nov  3 04:36 nvme0n1p3.img.gz
   -r--r--r-- 1 980M Nov  3 00:56 nvme0n1p4.img
   -r--r--r-- 1  13G Nov  3 01:06 nvme0n1p5.img
   ```

   As you can see, the compressed size of the Windows partition, partition number 3, is only 22GB, compared to the original partition size of 940GB. Again, this was possible because I backed up this partition when my computer was new.

## Restore

1. **Boot Using Live USB**

   On the computer that is being restored, boot an Ubuntu live USB, and open a terminal window.
2. **List Partition Information**

   The disk that I want to restore is `/dev/nvme0n1`. Replace `nvme0n1` with your disk. You can use the Disks application in Ubuntu to see a list of disks and their device names.

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
   ```

   The output will depend on how you had partitioned your disk while installing Ubuntu.

   ```
   Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   Disklabel type: gpt
   Disk identifier: 2CF060B8-D127-491A-80D6-6AE411E5A7B8

   Device             Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
   /dev/nvme0n1p1      2048     405503     403456   197M EFI System
   /dev/nvme0n1p2    405504   10172415    9766912   4.7G Linux filesystem
   /dev/nvme0n1p3  10172416  242595839  232423424 110.8G Linux filesystem
   /dev/nvme0n1p4 242595840 2000409230 1757813391 838.2G Linux filesystem
   ```
3. **Restore Partition Table**

   Run the following from computer that is being restored.

   Replace `/mnt/data/Backup/` with the existing backup location on your remote computer. Replace `remote_user` and `REMOTE_COMPUTER` accordingly.

   ```
   cd ~/
   rcp remote_user@REMOTE_COMPUTER:/mnt/data/Backup/nvme0n1.gpt ~/
   sudo sgdisk --load-backup=nvme0n1.gpt /dev/nvme0n1

   The operation has completed successfully.
   ```
4. **List (Restored) Partition Information**

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
   ```

   As you can see, the partition table of my disk was restored to the original the manufacturer partitions.

   ```
   Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   Disklabel type: gpt
   Disk identifier: 1C949023-866B-4764-B397-252D5125277C

   Device              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
   /dev/nvme0n1p1       2048     534527     532480   260M EFI System
   /dev/nvme0n1p2     534528     567295      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
   /dev/nvme0n1p3     567296 1972772863 1972205568 940.4G Microsoft basic data
   /dev/nvme0n1p4 1972772864 1974779903    2007040   980M Windows recovery environment
   /dev/nvme0n1p5 1974779904 2000396287   25616384  12.2G Microsoft basic data
   ```
5. **Tips**

   - You can actually restore each partition in parallel, using different terminal windows in step 7, below.  Just be sure to execute `sudo -i` in each new terminal window.
   - To monitor your connectivity during the backup process do the following.

     On the computer being restored, open a terminal and type:

     ```
     ping REMOTE_COMPUTER.local
     ```

     On the remote computer, open a terminal and type:

     ```
     ping <IP ADDRESS OF COMPUTER BEING RESTORED>
     ```

     (I think simply `ping ubuntu.local` may also work since you are running from a Live USB).
6. **Install Progress Monitoring Tool**

   Install a tool to view progress of the restore process in the terminal. This tool will be used in subsequent commands.

   ```
   sudo apt install pv
   ```

   `pv` shows a progress bar on the command-line, with the percent and time remaining (ETA). I found that the ETA was pretty accurate; this is very useful, because restoring a 1TB partition can take over a day. Note that an ETA of 1:12:05:40 translates to, 'one 24-hour day: twelve hours: five minutes: and forty seconds"; in other words, almost 36 hours!
7. **Restore Each Partition from Remote Computer**

   Run the following from the computer that is being restored.

   The backup files are copied from the `/mnt/data/Backup/` directory on the remote computer.

   Replace `/mnt/data/Backup/` with the existing backup location on your remote computer. Replace `remote_user` and `REMOTE_COMPUTER` accordingly.

   Use information from step 4 as the value for `pv -s`, so it can calculate your ETA. You can round up to the nearest MB,since this doesn't have to be exact; it's just to show you approximately how much time is remaining.

   Execute the `dd` command for each partition listed in step 4 above. For example, for each of my five partitions, I executed the following:

   ```
   sudo -i

   # (1) 260.0 MiB
   date; ssh remote_user@REMOTE_COMPUTER.local "dd if=/mnt/data/Backup/nvme0n1p1.img" | pv -s 260M | dd of=/dev/nvme0n1p1; date

   # (2) 16.0 MiB
   date; ssh remote_user@REMOTE_COMPUTER.local "dd if=/mnt/data/Backup/nvme0n1p2.img" | pv -s 16M | dd of=/dev

   # (3) 940.4 GiB
   date; ssh remote_user@REMOTE_COMPUTER.local "dd if=/mnt/data/Backup/nvme0n1p3.img.gz | gunzip -1 - " | pv -s 940G | dd of=/dev/nvme0n1p3; date

   # (4) 980.0 MiB
   date; ssh remote_user@REMOTE_COMPUTER.local "dd if=/mnt/data/Backup/nvme0n1p4.img" | pv -s 980M | dd of=/dev/nvme0n1p4; date

   # (5) 12.2 GiB
   date; ssh remote_user@REMOTE_COMPUTER.local "dd if=/mnt/data/Backup/nvme0n1p5.img" | pv -s 12G | dd of=/dev/nvme0n1p5; date
   ```

   Notice that for partition 3, we uncompress the backup file. If you had also compressed your other partition backup files, use `gunzip` for them as well.

   Here is an example of the output for partition number 4. You will need to enter the password for the remote machine. The password input prompt may be a little obscured by the progress output, but just type your remote password, and press enter.

   ```
   root@ubuntu:~ # sudo -i
   root@ubuntu:~ # date; ssh remote_user@REMOTE_COMPUTER.local "dd if=/mnt/data/Backup/nvme0n1p5.img" | pv -s 12G | dd of=/dev/nvme0n1p5; date
   Sun Feb 11 03:17:30 UTC 2018
   remote_user@REMOTE_COMPUTER's password:
   12.2GiB 0:33:01 [6.31MiB/s] [=========================================================================>] 101%            
   25616384+0 records in
   25616384+0 records out
   13115588608 bytes (13 GB, 12 GiB) copied, 1982.54 s, 6.6 MB/s
   Sun Feb 11 03:50:33 UTC 2018
   ```

   ## Notes on Performance

   I used 5 GNZ Wi-Fi (Wireless AC) for this process. The computer being backed up had an nvme drive, and the computer receiving the backup files had an SSD drive. The largest partition was 940 GB; it took over an hour to backup this partition, but it took 36 hours to restore it. Throughout the process Wi-Fi transfer rates fluctuated between ~4 MiB/s to ~12 MiB/s, sometimes dropping to 0MiB or briefly peeking at 16MiB.

   I made the backup when my machine was new from the manufacturer, so the unused nvme disk had "zeros" in all unused areas; this made the compression ratio and backup time of the 940GB partition very fast.

   Therefore, I highly recommend making a backup as the first step, when your computer is new, before booting into Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you make a compressed backup, you won't need anything like > 1 TB of storage for the backup.  The installed Windows 10 on a new machine should be no larger than about 40 GB, and you'll get close to 50% compression, so you'll "only" need about 20 GB or so of storage.  If you use a built-in Ubuntu backup utility, then restoring (if you need warranty service) can be done from the same Live media you used to make the backup (and presumably install).

The slightly trickier part will be recreating, exactly, the original partitions -- Windows machines no longer come with one large partition; instead, there's a "boot" partition, a Windows partition, and a data partition (at its simplest).  If you're concerned about warranty being voided or denied because of installing Ubuntu, you'll want to be sure you can put those partitions back in precisely the same location and size they were originally in.  Fortunately, `gparted` has an option to back up a partition, and later restore it precisely -- if you use that option to backup up each partition, in order, then make a compressed backup of those backups, you'll need the large storage only for so long as it takes to get from original Windows to your compressed, second generation backup -- and once more when/if you restore.

However, you can back up the boot and Windows partitions *into the untouched data partition*, then make the compressed backups of those onto your external medium.  Once that's done, if you want/need to restore, you'll make a partition large enough to restore the compressed backups, restore the partitions from the restored copies, then delete and recreate the data partition filling all the remaining space.